# NUnit async Setup not supported?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, asynchronous, nunit

I need to unit test a method which loads with data in async fashion.
I can easily run async tests methods via

```
[Test]
public async Task My_test_async() {
 // ... await something
}
```

But I also want the `Setup` method to be async. Because it prepares some data in mocked Db. This mocked db is of course also async (it has to implement the same interface).

So my setup method looks like this:

```
[Setup]
public async Task Setup() {
  var db = new InMemoryDbContext();
  // ... add sample data in db context
  // ... then save them
  await db.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

But this results in my tests being skipped by NUnit Runner
[image]

I am using NUnit version 3.0.1, NUnitTestAdapter.WithFramework version 2.0.0 and VisualStudio 2015 with Resharper 9.2

**Possible workarounds**

I can workaround this problem, but neither solution feels nice.

Workaround #1

Refactor Setup() method to be private, remove the [Setup] attribute from it, and call it in every test method. That way it can be awaited and tests will execute.

Workaround #2

Or I can make the Setup synchronous, and wrap the async code in `Task.Run().Result`, like this

```
var r = Task.Run(() => db.SaveChangesAsync()).Result;
```

But both workarounds are ugly.

Does anyone knows a better solution?

Comment: Your best bet is opening a issue on NUnit's issue tracker on GitHub. It should work though, AFAIK

Comment: See [this](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/60) GitHub issue.

Answer (score 32):

In NUnit3

```cs
[OneTimeSetUp]
public async Task OneTimeSetup()
{
    // fixture one time setup code, can use await here
}

[SetUp]
public async Task Setup()
{
    // per test setup, can use await here
}
```

Comment: For completeness, also available on SetUp attribute:  
`[SetUp]
public async Task Setup() { }`

Answer (score 12):

Work around #2 :D

```
[SetUp]
public void Setup()
{
    SetupAsync().Wait();
}

public async Task SetupAsync()
{
    var db = new InMemoryDbContext();
    // ... add sample data in db context
    // ... then save them
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Comment: I agree - there is no point in running the setup method (or even the test) as an async method. There's no harm in using Wait/Result

Comment: possible deadlock -1